# HTML template not working

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am trying to build a template with common header/footer.
for some reason,my other pages are not showing the template

My pages:

**layout/layout.xhtml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="../stylesheet/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <div id="templateHearderDiv" class="templateHearder">
      <h1> Test logo</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="contentBody">
      <ui:insert name="content">
        default content
      </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="templateFooterDiv" class="templateFooter">
      <p>  2016-2017. All Rights Reserved</p>
    </div>
  </h:body>
</h:html>
```

CSS, **stylesheet/template.css**

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

* { margin:0; padding:0; }

.templateHearder{
  background: #FFCF75;
  height: 10%;
}
.contentBody{
}
.templateFooter{
  height: 10%;
  background: #FFCF75;
}
.contentBody{
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;

}
.logoFont{
  font-family: "Impact";
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**home.xhtml**

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="/layout/layout.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">
    <h2>This is page1 content</h2>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**home.xhtml** is my welcome page, when i see that page the template is not shown.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was servlet mappings in web.xml.
Understanding their significance.

Answer (score 0):

We need default servlet handler(depends on the server).
The default servlet helps listing out directories,static resources etc.
I missed default servlet mappings and for that reason the template was not loaded.